# Equivalent of SHOW CREATE SCHEMA in Presto

Tags: presto

Is there an equivalent of SHOW CREATE SCHEMA in presto? I just want to see the value of the location field.

Answer (score 0):

Presto do not support `SHOW CREATE SCHEMA`. It only supports `SHOW CREATE` option for [VIEW](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/show-create-view.html) and [TABLE](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/show-create-table.html).